# #1064 SQL error... Can't find the cause

Tags: sql

This is my first question to this forum.
I am trying to make this table, but somehow I keep getting I have some kinds of syntax error near `Uemail` ~ `PRIMARY KEY` (. Other tables with similar SQL were all working, so I am really lost now. Can you find any errors?

```
CREATE TABLE LIKE(
Uemail VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
PURL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (Uemail, PURL) ,
FOREIGN KEY (Uemail) REFERENCES USER(Email) ,
FOREIGN KEY (PURL) REFERENCES PUSHPIN(URL)
);
```

Comment: `LIKE` is a keyword. Does it work if you change the table name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LIKE` is a keyword. Try a different name, or escape it with square brackets.

```
CREATE TABLE [LIKE](
    Uemail VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
    PURL VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (Uemail, PURL) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (Uemail) REFERENCES USER(Email) ,
    FOREIGN KEY (PURL) REFERENCES PUSHPIN(URL)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you should wrap the `LIKE` with backtickts this way: `` `LIKE` ``